# android support v4.jar

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-viewpager, slidingmenu

i have problem with android support v4.jar when i wanna adding slidingmenu in my apps.
i already using viewpager library on my apps which is use the support v4.jar too. when i'm adding new library (sliding menu), the jar mismatch. then i go to build path to correct it and using support v4.jar sliding menu, but support v4.jar sliding menu didnt support the viewpager script. how can the support v4.jar can be used for both viewpager and slidingmenu? and also how v4.jar can be used for viewpager, slidingmenu and zxing?

thanks,

SOLVED. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing, maybe post a link to the sliding menu library you're using.

Comment: i'm using library from jfeinstein10

Comment: Try updating the support library jar in the sliding menu project. It may be out of date with the one in yours.

Comment: I've used SlidingMenu and ViewPager. Just download the newest support jar and add it to every project. Works fine for me.

Comment: thx. yap thats the problem. i already solved it. thx by the way :D